# XRDP Opens some applications on actual desktop rather than remote port

Tags: command-line, display, xrdp, rdp

I have managed to get XRDP working, but now if I click some applications such as Terminal in my RDP client I don't see them. If I look at the machine I am remoting into (the RDP server machine) the application has been opened on it's display.

How do I get all applications to correctly open 'on' the remote display - ie the one I am actually in front of?

System:

Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.